# Is there an antonym for the idiom "...remains to be seen"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, antonyms

I was using "...the truth remains to be seen" in a sentence when I realized I meant the opposite of this. I'm looking a phrase antithetical to this idiom, that follows the same (empirical) line of thinking. Is there one?

Comment: What do **you** think "the truth remains to be seen" means, and what do **you** mean by "the opposite of" this meaning? There's not enough context here to answer the question as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> The truth is self-evident.

Comment: This was similar to Josh's answer but more succinct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be 'the truth will never be known'?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Vilmar, the “Could it be” phrase is rhetorical, ie has meaning similar to  “Perhaps it means”.  Also, this seems to me to be the right answer.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thank you. Yes it was a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

> The truth is patently obvious